# How to turn windows 10 menu bar black

Tags: windows-10, sublime-text-3

Is there any way to turn sublime(or system level) menu bar to black.
[image: Sublime]

Comment: Were you able to change the menu bar color?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the color of the menu bar from Windows 10 settings (title bar and other colors can be changed though).

What you can do is change the high contrast settings to sort of change the menu bar colors, but that usually isn't a good option.

You can create your own theme. I believe that way you can actually change the menu bar colors, but that probably isn't as easy it sounds, because you need to hack the theme's style files.

If you are good with regedit, you try to modify values in *Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors*. Beware, you may end up modifying more than you intended to. In conclusion there is no easy way to change the menu bar colors.